# "getActiveSheet" gets and changes the value of cell. I want to select a cell from a different sheet but I don't know the syntax for it

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, getActiveSheet changes the value within the same sheet. How do I select another sheet within the same Google Sheet?

Thank You!

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C1').setValue(cellFunction1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getSheetByName("sheetname") to get a specific sheet.

For example:

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange('A1').getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange('A2').getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange('C1').setValue(cellFunction1);
}
```

You can find the full reference documentation for the spreadsheet class [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Finally if you don't know the sheet names you may also be find the getSheets() method useful, which will return an array of all sheets in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Change

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

to

SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Name_of_the_sheet/tab")

---

### Reference

[getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))